# Redirect existing file to different url using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect an existing file to a different URL. I'm using the following and it has no effect. I've tried several variations of which don't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php3
# AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .php4

# This file exists, but this redirect doesn't work
RewriteRule ^show.php?id=review-1$ /review/1/super-baseball-2020/ [R=301,L]
```

Does it by chance have something to do with the url params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have query string in RewriteRule. RewriteRule matches only URL part that's why your new rule is not working. You need to have a separate RewriteCond to match QUERY string. It should be re-written like this:

```
# for external redirect from /shows.php?id=review-1 to /review/1/super-baseball-2020/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([^-]*)-(.*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/super-baseball-2020/? [R=301,L,NC]

# for internal redirect from /review/1/super-baseball-2020/ to /shows.php?id=review-1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ shows.php?id=$1-$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: That works out; however, since `/review/1/super-baseball-2020/` is actually a `RewriteRule` for `shows.php?id=review-1`, it gets into a infinite redirect loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to comment out/delete your existing rule: `RewriteRule ^show.php?id=review-1$ /review/1/super-baseball-2020/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: I did get rid of that. This is what's in my .htaccess

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /shows.php?id=$1-$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review-1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shows\.php$ /review/1/super-baseball-2020/ [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: I took your .htaccess and fixed it to remove any looping. Pls check my edited answer above.