# Rewrite URL to something that's not contained in the URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I understand that you can use mod rewrite to make URLs look nicer...

For example:

`www.myblog.com/articles/read.php?article_ID=1234`

to:

`www.myblog.com/read/1234`

by using:

`RewriteRule ^([^_]*)/([^_]*)$ /articles/$1.php?article_ID=$2`

Now what about adding things to the URL, that were not originally part of it?

For example if I would like the URL to be a description of the article (heading) instead of a number?

How can I achieve this:

`http://www.myblog.com/read/This_is_the_heading_of_a_very_interesting_article`

In order to retrieve the heading I would have to connect to my db, using the article ID... Does mod_rewrite have a way to call to a php script?

And (if that's even possible) what happens when 2 blog articles have the same heading?

The latter might be the reason why this couldn't work - but then again I feel like I have seen it many times...

I guess a fix could be to still add the unique identifier into the url to avoid confusion like:

`http://www.myblog.com/read/1234/This_is_the_heading_of_a_very_interesting_article`

Just wondering how that could be achieved, any advice appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use PHP to create the links. When the page loads you probably have extracted the article information from the DB including ID, title, text etc. When you build your link you will use the info from the database to create your pages with URL with titles. However it's the ID that matters. That's how you keep track so that duplicate titles are irrelevant.

I can change the title of your post with this link [Rewrite URL to something that's not contained in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354980/i-just-changed-the-title-because-it-doesnt-matter) however the title is ignored by the server when you go to it.

Check out this link as it may help you

[How to rewrite SEO friendly url's like stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-urls-like-stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks for the link - that was exactly my question... someone answered it:

`Then in your index.php, split the REQUEST_URI to parse out the /review/1/, look in the database for the title of the review with id of 1, pass it to your friendly URI (slug) function, and append it to the url, then redirect.`

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I would tend to use slashes as delimiters, since that tends to be how people thing - this means you can have have a title of "my_title_either/or", but that's usually ok.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /articles/$1.php?article_header=$2
```

You would be responsible yourself for making the article header unique. Your second version, with the unique id, would be

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /articles/$1.php?article_id=$2
```

I havent used $3 at all; if you have a unique id, you don't need anything else, though you could still use it if you want:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /articles/$1.php?article_id=$2&title=$3
```