# htaccess rewrite url like Stack Overflow

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Stack Overflow generates rewrite URLs,

so i need to know how i can do it like Stack Overflow?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-urls-like-stackoverflow => 200 ok.(without trailing slash)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-urls-like-stackoverflow/ => 200 ok.(with trailing slash)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/ => 301 redirect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364  => 301 redirect.
```

How i can do it with mod_rewrite ?

i have something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)[/]([^/]*) ./cat.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]



mydomain.com/999 => 404 not found.
mydomain.com/999/ => 200 ok.
mydomain.com/999/test => 200 ok.
mydomain.com/999/test/test2 => 200 ok.
mydomain.com/999/test/test2/test3 => 200 ok.
mydomain.com/999/test/test2/test3/test4 => 200 ok.
```

please let me know how i change RewriteRule ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex a bit by making trailing slash optional. Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ ./cat.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what i need. may i know how i can learn RewriteRules regular expression ? is there any book for this ?

Comment: @anubhava I'm doing something like `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC]` but it doesn't work. Only the post id show show up. Do I need to do search the database with the title as a GET parameter along with the id for this to work?

Comment: @maxxon15: Use `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]` and if not resolved please open a new question.

Comment: The rewriterule works great, however I now lost the ability to use $_GET['id] from the url like @maxxon15 was asking...  Any solution for this?

Comment: @ArabianMaiden: I need more details. Please open a new question

Comment: @anubhava Here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610284/how-to-getid-from-a-clean-url-like-mydomain-com-products-123-title-of-this

Comment: @UFO hello after 9 years! I got some nice documentation for you here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Might be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

**index.php:**

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = explode("/",substr($url,1));
```

Your links would be readable by PHP as follow:

`http://www.website.com/First/Second/Third`

`$url[0] >> 'First'`

`$url[1] >> 'Second'`

`$url[2] >> 'Third'`