# how to hide a php page from an address bar?

Tags: php

how to turn this **http://11.111.11.11/project_Folder/dist/hello.php**
to this **http://11.111.11.11/project_Folder/dist/** using php?

Comment: search for htaccess rewrite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess rewrite url like Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012045/htaccess-rewrite-url-like-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 2):

you can make  `http://11.111.11.11/project_Folder/dist/hello.php` to `http://11.111.11.11/project_Folder/dist/hello` using `.htaccess` below is example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will basically make the server take a /hello request and because there is no /hello on the server it will load /hello.php instead. Basically this says if the File in the URL can’t be found on the server then in the backend load it again using .php.

Comment: at web-root directory of your website near index.php