# How to $_GET['id'] from a clean url like "example.com/products/123/title-of-this-product"?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like my URL to look like this:

```
example.com/products/123/title-of-this-product
```

The actual URL is this:

```
example.com/products.php?id=123&title=title-of-this-product
```

The `.htaccess` file correctly interprets my URLs so that users who are on this page only see the clean URL. However, if I try to use `$_GET['id']` on the `products.php` page, the script crashes because it doesn't recognize any `id` in the URL.

`.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ ./products.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

`products.php` code:

```
$product_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "Error! I can't find your product!";
```

How can I retain the URL parameters for PHP functions if I want a clean URL?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It's in the same folder as the rest of my files. Is the location of my .htaccess file relevant to the issue?

Comment: So, in the document root? Effectively at `example.com/.htaccess`? Yes, it is relevant since the regex won't match - it assumes you are in a `products` subdirectory.

Comment: Correct. The idea is that the products.php file cannot interpret the `id` parameter once I clean up the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have 2 problems here...

1. `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) is enabled and it's this that is serving `products.php`.
2. Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* is incorrect and won't match the requested URL.

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
> ```

You need to disable `MultiViews` (you have explicitly enabled it). It is MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) that is serving your `products.php` file (without any URL parameters), not the mod_rewrite directive that follows. MultiViews essentially allows extensionless URLs with minimal effort, however, it can be the cause of unexpected conflicts (with mod_rewrite) - as in this case.

Your `RewriteRule` directive is not actually doing anything. If the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$` does not match the requested URL (`/products/123/title-of-this-product`), so the directive is not actually processed at all (although MultiViews would still override this even if it did).

Try it like this instead:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ products.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

You were missing `products` from the start of the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Without `products/` at the start of the regex it would only match if you are in a `/products/` subdirectory, ie. `/products/.htaccess`. The `RewriteRule` directive matches relative to the location of the `.htaccess` file itself.

Comment: So I was ignoring the main problem!... Tried your solution and it works like a charm. Just to clarify, PHP does in fact read the original (unmodified) URL regardless of which functions I use to manipulate the URL?

Comment: In case someone else crosses this issue - I've also had to change all of the header and footer links (image, css, and js folders, plugins etc) to Absolute paths (like https://example.com/images/123.png) because the errors that are thrown don't explicitly tell you why your files aren't rendering.

Comment: @ArabianMaiden "PHP does ... read the original (unmodified) URL regardless of which functions I use to manipulate the URL?" - Yes, PHP can read the originally requested URL in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal regardless of whether MultiViews or RewriteRule rewrote the request. And yes, when you are rewriting multiple path depths you need to use root-relative or absolute URLs to your static assets (not _relative_ URLs). See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/86450/1243

Comment: ...in fact, the following recent StackOverflow question (and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564372/369434)) covers the same issue regarding relative URL-paths and URL-rewriting. It's an issue that keeps cropping up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563233/js-and-css-rendering-issues-after-htaccess-file-url-rewrite-rule @ArabianMaiden