# Rewriting $_GET parameters as SEO friendly?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I want to rewrite my URL so that instead of

```
page.php?id=XXX&server=YYY&realm=ZZZ
```

It shows

```
page/XXX/YYY/ZZZ.php
```

I know how to do it using mod_rewrite, but only for one parameter, not 3. How would a rewrite code for this look like?

Comment: This depends heavily on the framework you are using, e.g. Wordpress, Laravel, ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite SEO friendly url's like stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168364/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-urls-like-stackoverflow)

Comment: No framework...